# Update Android app on Google Play

Tags: android, upload, google-play, apk, updates

of course there are a lot similar questions and I really read through, but none of them completely answered my question:

I want to update my current app (already prod) on Google Play, but it says I need to change the versionCode -> 1 does already exist.
But I changed or added this in the AndroidManifest.xml, also the versionName.

You must know, I didn't add any versionCode or versionName in my first upload, could this cause the problem?

Do I have to delete the app now and re-upload it?
I surely used the same keystore and credentials

Steps done:

- updated the AndroidManifest.xml
- android:versionCode="2"
- android:versionName="1.0">
- created a new signed apk
- tried to upload

Another question:
Do I really need to use the same apk-filename?

xml manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ibma.ibmaapp"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ibma.ibmaapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: play store developer page shows the version code in apk listing under version column. what is it showing?

Comment: it shows 1(1.0)
Is there a possibility to check the version of my new apk file?
I read somewhere that it is possible to compare two apk files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it works...

1. updated Android Studio to 0.8.0
2. updated my APIs (to API 20: Android L)

   - changed following project settings: (under "File > Project Structure")
   - Compile SDK Version: android-L
   - Build Tools Version: 20.0.0
3. changed the selected API for the graphical Layout (see link below)
   [have a look at this blog](http://thodorisbais.blogspot.co.at/2014/07/how-to-solve-exception-raised-during.html?showComment=1405086784693#c3124756814063866905)
   (Thank you, Thodoris Bais! ;-) )
4. Had to change the build.gradle file and add the correct VersionCode

   - this was the reason why I could not generate apk's with different VersionCodes
   - it was still set to versionCode=1 though in the manifest it was set to two

I checked the new apk file with the aapt command and the versionCode was set to 2, finally!

**Now my last queston would be:**
Do I always have to update the AndroidManifest.xml and the build.gradle file on my own - shouldn't they just synchronize?

Best regards,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

For the first question - Are you sure you saved the changes to the manifest? Seems silly, but it's a mistake I make all the time.
For the second question - You can change the .apk filename to whatever you'd like; there's no need to keep it the same.

Comment: yes I saved it - I added the manifest above
Also I updated my SDK - now I have to zipalign my apks manually
I think I'll stop updating as soon my Version works again totally fine - I'm getting sich of all these bugs a new update brings with it...

Comment: As I did the zipaligning on my own I also checked it with the aapt command, you can see the result here:
http://s15.postimg.org/cyoi5b9y3/Zip_Align_aapt.jpg

Comment: Any ideas what could be the problem?
Now I'm using Android Studio 0.8.0 and fixed the problems.
It now generates the signed, zipaligned apk on its own.
But still it's not possible to upload it - same result when checking the new file with aapt in command line... (screenshot in comment above)